# TYPO3 How can I wrap an iframe (RTE) with TypoScript?

Tags: iframe, typo3, typoscript, rte

I'm using TYPO3 7.6 with `fluid styled content` and I've allowed my editor to insert an `iframe` into the Rich Text Editor (RTE or htmlarea). The `iframe` is shown, because of this [Snippet](http://blog.webentwickler.at/eingebette-objekte-object-embed-iframe-im-rte-von-typo3/). That's fine.

Now I want to wrap this `iframe` with `typoscript`, because the iframe must be responsive, so I need sth. like that, as a wrapper:

```
<div class="embed-container">
    <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7DRU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.embed-container {
  position: relative; 
  padding-bottom: 56.25%; /* ratio 16x9 */
  height: 0; 
  overflow: hidden; 
  width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
.embed-container iframe {

  position: absolute; 
  top: 0; 
  left: 0; 
  width: 100%; 
  height: 100%; 
}
```

**How can I wrap the `iframe`from TYPO3-RTE with some HTML-Code?**

I've tried sth. like this ... but it doesn't work.

```
### wrap iframe at RTE
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    externalBlocks := addToList(iframe)
    externalBlocks {
        iframe.stripNL = 1
        iframe.callRecursive = 1
        iframe.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser = 1
        iframe.callRecursive.tagStdWrap.HTMLparser.tags.iframe {
            fixAttrib.class.default = classOfiframe
            wrap = <div>|</div>
        }
    }
}
```

or

```
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.iframe = TEXT
lib.parseFunc_RTE.tags.iframe {
    wrap = <div class="test">|</div>
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Security side-note

Allowing your editors to hand-craft HTML raises the chance that your website is compromised by XSS (cross-site-scripting). It's not suggested to allow direct HTML input, especially if you cannot fully trust your editors.

### TypoScript adjustments

You're TypoScript was almost fine, only the levels where you applied the properties were wrong.

The following example puts the question in a whole picture. The part in the beginning is basically solved by fetching content elements - in this regard it initializes the state to be parsed. Only the `lib.parseFunce_RTE` adjustments are required in your scenario.

```
# Simulating some content
page = PAGE
page.10 = TEXT
page.10.value (
  <p>Before</p>
  <iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7DRU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
  <p>After</p>
  <main>Not parsed...</main>
)
page.10.parseFunc =< lib.parseFunc_RTE

# Adjusting parsing instructions for IFRAMES
lib.parseFunc_RTE {
    allowedTags := addToList(iframe)

    externalBlocks := addToList(iframe)
    externalBlocks {
      iframe.stripNL = 1
      iframe.stdWrap.wrap = <div class="frame-wrapper">|</div>
    }
}
```

### Generated output

This produces the following output - it's expected that the `<main>` tag is encoded, because it's not defined to be handled. A `nonTypoTagStdWrap.HTMLparser` statement is responsible for this encoding of non-matched tags.

```
<p class="bodytext">Before</p>
<div class="frame-wrapper">
<iframe width="560" height="315" src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/7DRU" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
</div>
<p class="bodytext">After</p>
<p class="bodytext">  &lt;main&gt;Not parsed...&lt;/main&gt;</p>
```

Find more details in the [`parseFunc`TypoScript reference](https://docs.typo3.org/typo3cms/TyposcriptReference/Functions/Parsefunc/Index.html#)

Comment: thanks oliver. works perfect. very easy but I'm not a typoscript-pro ;), so thanks for the link to the reference.